# I cannot seem to output certain characters

Tags: c++, winapi

Before when I did `std::cout << char(1);` I used to get the smiley face as an output, now I am getting a box with a question mark inside it. I'v been told I need to change the code page so I did with code below, but without any result, I also used `SetConsoleCP(437)`.

```
int main()
{
   SetConsoleOutputCP(437);
   std::cout << char(1);
}
```

So please can tell me a way to output the control character of the ASCII like they used to be.

Note: This issue started when I switch from XP to Windows10.

Edit:
In the this link https://ibb.co/jH1MS7q, this what i get when using chcp and all 256 character displayed in my console, what I want to print is the one in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#/media/File:Codepage-437.png

Comment: What is the default code page on Windows XP? Are you using that code page?

Comment: Sorry, just rewinding for a moment to unpack this. You _JUST SWITCHED_ from Windows XP??? Are you in the Medical Software profession?

Comment: @Paddy I switch yes, but last time I used xp was 2013

Comment: VLL, I do not know, i am currently working on windows10, all I remember, back in 2013 and before, I used to program console games, and I used char(1) as a Hero, and char(2) as an enemy, not they are gone

Comment: @Ninja: If you want the person you are responding to to be notified of your comment, then you must use the `@` syntax when writing the person's name. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment for further information.

Comment: I don't think modern console fonts really care about the IBM PC code page anymore. At least, not those special glyphs for control characters.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I already know that but I forget, thanks anyway

Comment: Code point 1 in the ASCII table is assigned to `SOH` (Start of Header). This is a **non-printable** character. The real bug here is that you hoped for a reliable observable behavior when printing a non-printable character. The path to a solution is via accepting that this had been wrong all along. That out of the way, what *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable It is printable, I asked some of my friends, they have no issue with printing it, I guess because we have different configurations. In the following link you can see for yourself that all the control code are printable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 the following link is what i used to have back in 2013 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#/media/File:Codepage-437.png

Comment: Try using the Unicode smiling face☺(`0x263A`) instead. `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); std::wcout << L"\x263a";`.

Comment: @Thanks zett42,  I already know the code you just point, for that I am not trying to write a unicode letter, I trying to know why the controle code used to be printable, but now they does not, also I am trying to find why SetConsoleOutput does not work, in the this link https://ibb.co/jH1MS7q this what i get when using chcp and all 256 character desplayed in my console, what I want to print is the one in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#/media/File:Codepage-437.png

Comment: [Control characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) do not have specific graphical representation. It depends on console implementation how this charters will be visible. It may even depend on hardware (if screen is in text mode, which is rarely uses now)! Maybe [this can help](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) too.

Comment: ASCII code point 1 is non-printable. If you insist on using "extended ASCII" or code-page encoding, best of luck to you. Just a reminder, the 80's are over. Using technology from times before your grandparents decided to reproduce doesn't immediately appear to be appealing. Now the real question is: Why are you trying to avoid applying the solution?

Comment: @IInspectable the question seems simple to me - why does something which used to work not work any more?  I don't have an immediate answer but it seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: *"why does something which used to work not work any more?"* - The answer is equally simple. This happens when you use a system outside its specification.

Comment: @IInspectable and what specification would that be?  I'd think that 40 years of working exactly the same way would form a de facto standard.  Don't try to weasel out of it by claiming the ASCII standard, because code page 437 has always been a *superset* of ASCII.

Comment: @MarkRansom The font face used by the console host has not ever been part of the specification of the console API.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is a lookup table.

On Windows we need a little extra help to make sure things are set-up properly.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
  
  struct OutputCodePage
  {
    UINT original_cp;

    OutputCodePage( UINT cp )
    : original_cp{GetConsoleOutputCP()}
    { SetConsoleOutputCP( cp ); }

   ~OutputCodePage()
    { SetConsoleOutputCP( original_cp ); }
  };
  
  OutputCodePage output_code_page( CP_UTF8 );
#endif
```

Everything else works the same on both Windows and Linux (and OS X).

```
#include <iostream>

const char * CP437[] =  // I choose to represent 0 (nul) as 32 (space)
{
  " ", "☺", "☻", "♥", "♦", "♣", "♠", "•", "◘", "○", "◙", "♂", "♀", "♪", "♫", "☼",
  "►", "◄", "↕", "‼", "¶", "§", "▬", "↨", "↑", "↓", "→", "←", "∟", "↔", "▲", "▼",
  " ", "!", "\"","#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/",
  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?",
  "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
  "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\"","]", "^", "_",
  "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
  "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "⌂",
  "Ç", "ü", "é", "â", "ä", "à", "å", "ç", "ê", "ë", "è", "ï", "î", "ì", "Ä", "Å",
  "É", "æ", "Æ", "ô", "ö", "ò", "û", "ù", "ÿ", "Ö", "Ü", "¢", "£", "¥", "₧", "ƒ",
  "á", "í", "ó", "ú", "ñ", "Ñ", "ª", "º", "¿", "⌐", "¬", "½", "¼", "¡", "«", "»",
  "░", "▒", "▓", "│", "┤", "╡", "╢", "╖", "╕", "╣", "║", "╗", "╝", "╜", "╛", "┐",
  "└", "┴", "┬", "├", "─", "┼", "╞", "╟", "╚", "╔", "╩", "╦", "╠", "═", "╬", "╧",
  "╨", "╤", "╥", "╙", "╘", "╒", "╓", "╫", "╪", "┘", "┌", "█", "▄", "▌", "▐", "▀",
  "α", "ß", "Γ", "π", "Σ", "σ", "µ", "τ", "Φ", "Θ", "Ω", "δ", "∞", "φ", "ε", "∩",
  "≡", "±", "≥", "≤", "⌠", "⌡", "÷", "≈", "°", "∙", "·", "√", "ⁿ", "²", "■", "\xA0"
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "ASCII table:\n ";
  for (int y = 0;  y < 16;  y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0;  x < 16;  x++)
    {
      std::cout << " " << CP437[y * 16 + x];
    }
    std::cout << "\n ";
  }
}
```

Make sure you save the file as UTF-8 without a BOM, and compile with UTF-8 source files. (Modern compilers do that automatically, so you shouldn’t find it a problem.)

There are plenty of other ways to mess around with it, but this is the basic idea behind *all* translation tables.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. According to [SetConsoleOutputCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp#remarks), it is better to use [EnumSystemCodePages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-enumsystemcodepagesa) to Enumerate the code pages that are either installed on or supported by an operating system and Make sure your code page data file is fine.
[image]

Comment: I don’t think a system exists where CP437 is invalid...